# Bash - Extract key value by name from arbitrary text?

Tags: bash

I'd like to have a simple script that lets me pass it any text, and it pulls out a value for a key from the string.

I'd like this to be flexible, and accept XML or JSON input, and even poorly formed input, like text from a log.

e.g. given any of the following inputs, it should be able to pull out the value of the `test` key.

e.g.

`$ echo "test:5 hi there" | extract_key_value test`

should result in

```
5
```

Note that I don't care what it's written in, so node, ruby, etc is fine by me, but portability (Linux/osx) is nice ;-)

#### input1

```
this is test:5 i saw a value
```

#### input2

```
this is test:'another value' i saw a value
```

#### input3

```
this is test=5 i saw a value
```

#### input4

```
test='a string value here'
```

#### input5

```
my data
on line 2 test='a string value here'
more data
```

My quick crack at this is the following, which I feel can be improved greatly and feels like it should be solved somewhere!

## extract_key_value

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  IT=$(cat <<EOF
  
  Helps you extract a key value from a string, typically a log msg

  usage: key {keyBeginDelim} {keyEndDelim}

  e.g. given "asd f asdf asdf test=easy asdf me=you" as input

  extract_key_value test        
  => returns easy
EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

INPUT=$(cat -)
KEY="$1"

function getVal()
{
  DELIM1="$1"
  DELIM2="$2"
  echo "$INPUT" | awk -F "$DELIM1" '{print $2}' | awk -F "$DELIM2" '{print $1}'
}

# Try whatever the user passed in or defaults for delims
if [ -n "$2" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$2" "$3")
fi

# Try other use cases
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY:'" "'")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY='" "'")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY=\"" "\"")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY:\"" "\"")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY:" " ")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY=" " ")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY=" ";")
fi
if [ -z "$IT" ]
then
  IT=$(getVal "$KEY:" ";")
fi

echo "$IT"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
extract_key_value() {
  pcregrep -Mo1 "(?sx)
   (?:
       \Q$1\E      # key literally
     | \"\Q$1\E\"  # same in double quotes
     | '\Q$1\E'    # same in single quotes
   )
   [=:]
   (?|  # branch reset
       '(.*?)'
     | \"(.*?)\"
     | ([^\"'\s]+)
   )"
}
```

- `-M`: multiline match (to allow `test:'foo\nbar'`...)
- `-o1`: output the text matched by the first capture group (see below about *branch reset*).
- `(?sx)`: enable the `s` flag (make `.` match newline characters as well) and `x` flag (allow that multiline with  comment format)
- `\Q$1\E` the content of `$1` (the first argument to the function) is to be taken literally. That assumes it doesn't contain `\E` itself. In ksh93-like shells like `bash`, you can replace `$1` with `${1//\\E/\\E\\\\E\\Q}` to work around that.
- `(?|.(.).|.(.).)` branch reset. The numbering of the capture group starts from 1 after each `|`, so `-o1` will return the first capture group that matches in any of the alternation.
- `'.*?'`. `.*?` is the non-greedy variant of `.*`, so `'.*'` will match from `'` to the first `'` after that.
- `\s`: any whitespace character.

That doesn't try to address corner cases like the `\x` encodings in json, the embedding of quotes within quotes (which is done differently depending on the language). It doesn't allow whitespace on either side of the `:` or `=`. All those can be addressed if need be. That will depend on the type of exact input you're trying to process.

Comment: sweet! this seems great... one other use case occurred to me - that being that the `KEY` itself is quoted, matching whatever the value has... e.g. `"test":"5"` or `'test':'5'` ... thoughts? thanks regardless!

Comment: @Brad, see edit.

Comment: That totally works - there was one minor fix required, that being that for the single quote case, the `$q` should be `$1`... thanks a bunch Stéphane Chazelas !

Comment: @Brad, thanks. I've now fixed the `$q` typo.

Answer (score 3):

A example with grep:

```
function extract_key_value() {
    egrep -o "$1[:=]['\"[:alnum:]]+" | egrep -o "['\"[:alnum:]]+$" | egrep -o "[[:alnum:]]+"
}
```

```
echo -e "on line 1\ntest:123 asasas\non line 3\ntest='abc'\non line 5" | extract_key_value test
```